# unable to get submenu items in Angular js application along with Angular Snap

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

Even though the dropdown menu is coming fine with Angular Snap but I am facing problem in showing sub menu. Can any one help me in fixing this. Please find my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mSHmNxnUrzuL8t1BfCUp?p=preview), none of the items under 'Filter Sub Menu' are getting displayed.

The following is my menu and submenu :

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen" ng-style="{ 'position':'relative'}">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
      Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ng-style="{'float' : 'right'}">
      <li><a href ng-click="callHandle()" snap-toggle> Apply </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href ng-click="callHandle()"> Cancel </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href ng-click="callHandle()">Save</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href ng-click="callHandle()">Save As</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href>Filter Sub Menu</a>  
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li ng-repeat="filt in savedFilterList "> <a href> {{filt.filter_name}}</a> 
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I can see the elements in the dom. In bootstrap 3 they removed submenu, i think your styling for the submenu is missing.

Comment: yes you are right. I have updated the plunker with the fix it is working fine. But the sub menu items are going behind snap content. As a result, sub menu items are not fully visible. How can I bring them to front?